# High availability in AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, high-availability, aws-sqs-fifo, sqslistener

1. I have a microservice which pushes the messages to the SQS Fifo queue. If in future the SQS is down, How can I configure a secondary SQS as a failover. Could also please mind in explaining how AWS manages the high availability of SQS.
2. IS SQS a region based service or an Availability-zone based service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the SLA [here](https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/). SQS is regional, and highly-available within each region.

Here's a guide to [Disaster Recover on SQS](https://disaster-recovery.workshop.aws/en/services/app_integration/sqs.html), which provides suggested architectures for:

1. Active-Active
2. Backup & Restore
3. Pilot Light
4. Warm Standby

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my query. Thanks for the links provided.